# Annotated Timeline Chart Google Visualization

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm trying to create a stock chart using the Annotated Google Chart Timeline. http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html

I have data from 9-5 every day, but notice that the chart covers a 24 hr period. Is there a way to change the day to day timeframe from 24hr to 9-5?

Answer (score 1):

If the x axis is date anyways, why does it matter what hour it arrives? Couldn't you just put it as a footnote? Or are you displaying the hour on the x axis?

Could you post a sample of your code so we can look at it in:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#annotated_time_line

Thx

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the code I post won't be of any use since the API data that I'm using is private. The reason why it matters on time is because I might have 100 datapoints within the hour and want to plot each of those datapoints. So yes, I am displaying the hour/minute on the x axis. Therefore, since I only have data from 9AM to 5PM, I'd like each day on the x-axis to reflect just that time period and not 12AM to 12PM.